# Unable to see Attendee list on event object in lightning experience in Spring'19

Tags: event, lightning-events, eventlogfile

As per the below link of salesforce release notes, we can now see the attendee list on the event object in the lightning experience without enabling setting up the lightning sync.

Salesforce Release notes: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_calendar_attendees.htm

I'm testing this functionality on my Spring 19 enabled Org. But, I'm not able to see the attendee list on the event object in lightning experience. Is there any other configuration setting needs to be done?

Comment: I just added the `Attendees field to the page layout for events` as mentioned in [documentation](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_calendar_attendees.htm), I was able to see the Attendees in lightning without any additional setup. You are looking at wrong page layout where attendees is not added?

Comment: Thanks Rahul, After adding the Attendees field to the page layout of events, Attendees list appear in the lightning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the documentation [Add Attendees Without Setting Up Lightning Sync](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_calendar_attendees.htm) with the pre-requisite:

> To allow reps to add or remove attendees in Lightning Experience and the Salesforce app, **add the Attendees field to the page layout for events**.